# Show dynamic h1 title on taxonomy listing page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a small whisky review blog which contains many tags. For some reason, on these tag listing pages, the page title (for example, *Scotch Whisky* for http://themashing.com/t/scotch-whisky) is not showing.

Basically, what I want is the title to show right before the list of articles. So if I visited the Japanese Whisky listing page then *Japanese Whisky* would be the page title.

Why doesn't the title appear? How do I fix this?

Comment: So it looks like it's a D8 site. In D8, page titles are handled by a block region so my guess would be, you just need to set that block region on the blocks admin UI page for the taxonomy and then it should work. (Note, I added the "8" tag to your post.)